# how to separate two or more returned variables in the $.post method in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i need to seperate two variables which i got from the server and i m using $.post method. but when i m doing it i m getting the combined mixed value from this method. here is the code

```
$(".spot_me").click(function()
    {
        var idea = $(this).attr("id");
        var idea1 = $(this).attr("data");
        alert(idea);
        alert(idea1);
        $.post('spot_me.php', 'val=' + idea + '&tim=' + idea1, function (data)
        {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

here var id is a userid. i wish to get the coordinates which this user had stored in the database. my php code for abc.php is

```
<?php
session_start();
$value = $_POST['val'];
$value1 = $_POST['tim'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","******","anurag");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT latitude,longitude FROM notifications WHERE uid='$value' AND time='$value1' ");
if(!$result2)
{
    echo "Error in query";
}
else
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    $lat = $row['latitude'];
    $lon = $row['longitude'];
    echo $lat;
    echo $lon;
}
```

?>

now i want to get this lat and lon value separately in my jquery $.post method in the parameter data. how can i get these values separately and "I WANT TO STORE THEM IN TWO DIFFERENT VARIABLES IN $.POST METHOD" how can i do this

Comment: no language I know can return more than 1 value. the best way is you can convert your 2 values to a json string `json_encode` from PHP and at jQuery you can decode the string to get both.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can privide me the code. i have never used json before so i dont know anything about it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use JSON to communicate between the languages.

Your PHP will transform the array into JSON:

```
else
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

And your javascript will treat the `data` as an object, because you've told the `.post()` function to expect `json`

```
   var post_str = 'val=' + idea + '&tim=' + idea1;
   $.post('spot_me.php', post_str, function (data)
    {
        alert(data.latitude);
        alert(data.longitude);
    }, 'json');
```

Comment: +1 you posted a better solution than mine while i was typing :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose a mode of response - maybe json (my preference) or xml
2. Construct your response with your server code
3. Parse that response with jQuery, with jQuery.parseXML() or jQuery.parseJSON() for json and xml respectively

Comment: please can you provide me a code. i have never used json before. i dont know how to do it :(

Comment: {"lat": "30", "lon": "34"} would be the json structure

Comment: look up json_encode. with it you can convert an array into a json string

Answer (score 0):

At PHP

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
echo json_encode($row);
```

At jQuery

```
$.post('spot_me.php', 'val=' + idea + '&tim=' + idea1, function (data)
{
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(response.latitude);
    alert(response.longitude);
});
```

This is just an indicator oh how to do it, and not tested.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by returning you output as JSon and then parse that JSON in Javascript.

In PHP file do like this: (instead of returning two variables)

```
echo json_encode(array('latitude' => $row['latitude'],'longitude'=> $row['longitude']));

Response will be like this (test values use)
{"latitude":123,"longitude":456}
```

in you Jquery Ajax code where you return response use JSON parse method

```
 var obj = $.parseJSON(data );
 alert( obj.latitude)
 alert( obj.longitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

//From the server

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
return json_encode($row);
```

//and on the client

```
var dataasjson = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(dataasjson, function(index, element) {
         element.name //this is your label i.e databse field name as key  
         dataasjson[element.name] //this is your long/lat value
        });
```